# Backbone calling Controller method from Views

Tags: backbone.js

[new to Backbone]
Working on a schedule App .use case is.

1) User Clicks reschedule button . [in View] 
2) Fetch available schedule . [in Controller]
3) User Selects one of schedule. [in View]
4) Post Updated schedule list to server. [in Controller]
5) Re render View

Issue is (1),(3) are on View and (2),(4) are on Controller. 
I need to route View -> Route -> Controller. for each step.
Is this the right way to pass events to controller . Is there a better way available ??
Is this the case for using Backbone.Events.

Folder Structure. [using Require , Backbone ]

```
├───app
│   ├───managers
│   ├───models
│   ├───utils
│   └───views
├───lib
└───tpl
```

Schedule Model.

```
    Schedule = Backbone.Model.extend({
                initialize: function () {
                    console.log("Schedule model initialized");
                }
            }),
```

ScheduleView :

```
    events : {
                "click #cancel_login_trip" : "cancelLoginTrip",
                "click #cancel_logout_trip" : "cancelLogoutTrip",
            },

    cancelLoginTrip : function(){
                var tripindex = this.model.get('previousIndex')+1;
                tripindex  = "login_"+tripindex;
                Backbone.history.navigate('schedule/cancel/'+tripindex, {trigger:true,replace:true});   
            },
```

Route

```
 cancelSchedule : function (tripindex) {
            var t = tripindex.split("_");
            var dic={};
            dic.tripindex = parseInt(t[1]);
            dic.triptype = t[0];
            scheduleManager.cancelSchedule(dic);
        },
```

Schedule Manager [ Controller ] :

```
    this.cancelSchedule = function(dic){
                console.log("inside cancel schedule");
                console.log(dic);
                index = dic.tripindex;
                scheduleDaysize = configManager.getFeatureConfig(Constants.SCHEDULE,Constants.SCHEDULE_DAYS_AFTER);
                myAnalyticsLogger.debug(LogMessages.REQUEST_TO_DISPLAY_SCHEDULE + index);
                if(index<0){
                    var errorText= 'past schedule can not be viewed ';
                    errorModel.set({errorText:errorText,response:""});
                    return;
                }
                if(index >= scheduleCollection.length && scheduleDaysize != null){              
                    var errorText= 'this schedule can not be cancelled ';
                    errorModel.set({errorText:errorText,response:""});
                    return;
                }
                updateScheduleOnServer(scheduleCollection.length, 
                            scheduleCollection.length+scheduleDaysize); 
            };
```

Comment: 1. show some code
2. Never knew there was a thing called `controller` in backbone!

Comment: there is nothing as `controller` in backbone, just move the controller code to view, there is no need to pass events out of view.

Comment: that won't be possible for me as code base is huge i have taken over from earlier dev .

Comment: hmm... in that case `Backbone.Events` would be more suitable. Views trigger events and controllers listen to those events.

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach would be create many small views, and have on large model with all logic and drop the middle controller. If this is not an option, best way of decoupling imho would be through global event model

```
var vent = {}
_.extend(vent,Backbone.Events);

vent.on()
vent.trigger()
```

you can have it global for all application, or specific for a part of the domain